# Distinct impls for a same struct, where only one of them is accessible?

Tags: rust, types

I'm making a game engine, and I would like to know if it's possible to have two different impls for a same struct that are not both accessible at compile time.

In my case, I have a `Transform` struct for my objects, and I'm making UI. Idealy, the UI `Transform` is the exact same struct as the `Transform`, with the same type. This allows the engine to iterate over all objects, scene or UI, and make no distinction between the two (the UI will have a separate shader of course, that will interpret the UI transform correctly). This avoids code duplication between scene objects and UI.

The thing is, I want the `UiTransform` to have it's own methods, that are proper to it, and the same thing for the regular transform. I don't want someone to call a ui method on a regular transform, that could mess it up.

What I tried:

The first thing that came to mind was type aliasing. Something like so :

```rust
struct Transform {...}

impl Transform {...} // regular transform methods

type UiTransform = Transform;

impl UiTransform {...} // ui transform methods
```

Now of course, this does not work, as all methods are accessible for both types. If there was a way to make this work, it would be my best solution.

I also though of zero-sized structs and generics, to make a compile time distinction between the two:

```rust
struct Transform3D;
struct TransformUI;

struct Transform<T> {...} // transform with phantom data for T

impl Transform<Transform3D> {...} // this allows transform 3D only methods

impl Transform<TransformUI> {...} // this allows transform UI only methods
```

But with this, my transforms do not have the same type, so I can't iterate through all my transforms, and this is the same as having two different structs.

Finally, I could make a `TranformImpl` and `UiTransformImpl` as traits, with `Transform` implementing both, and they will only be accessible if the user bring the trait into scope. But this feels way too much, I would like proper implementation for the struct, not some traits that could be implemented on other things.

Are there ways in Rust to create two distinct implementation for a struct, and hide one of them with a compile-time only flag ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an underlying type, `AnyTransform` (or whatever), and store it in the engine (`Vec<AnyTransform>`) and iterate over this.

Then, you can create wrappers `Transform` and `UiTransform` that have a single field of type `AnyTransform`, and only export those. This way, the engine can treat transforms uniformly, but from the user point of view, they're different types.

Converting between *owned* instances of the wrapper types and `AnyTransform` is straightforward: just `Wrapper(any_transform)` or `wrapper.0` for the other way around. Converting between *references* of them is more involved, but if you mark the wrapper types as `#[repr(transparent)]`, you can leverage the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck) crate with its [`TransparentWrapper`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.TransparentWrapper.html) trait and derive macro to do that safely.